# Oracle Schema tables row count

Tags: sql, linux, oracle11g, count, row

Oracle: 11g
OS: Linux

I have this very tricky questions which I am trying to solve but not able to get definite answers...
I did search on google...etc but not luck with my requirement...

Schema statistics are not reliable so want to query dba_tables.. 
also don't want to create any procedures or functions under database.. just trying to achieve with simple SQL.

Q.
How to spool all table row count of a particular schema and also display table_name?

A.
I can display count easily in spool but not able to get table name beside count..

e.g.

```
Table_Name Count
tab1 200
tab2 500
tab3 300
```

with below I can get count but not able to figure out table_name display in result...

```
spool runme.sql

select 'select count(*) from '|| owner || '.' || table_name || ';' 
from dba_tables
where owner = 'user1'
order by table_name;

spool off
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function like this, but it will be very slow:

```
create or replace
function get_rows( p_tname in varchar2 ) return number
as
    l_columnValue    number default NULL;
begin
    execute immediate
       'select count(*)
          from ' || p_tname INTO l_columnValue;

    return l_columnValue;
end;
/

select user, table_name,
       get_rows( user||'.'||table_name) cnt
  from user_tables
/
```

Code taken from this answer on Tom Kyte's site:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1660875645686

**Without a function call** it is also possible:

```
select
table_name,
to_number(
   extractvalue(
      xmltype(
         dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name))
,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
from user_tables;
```

From the tip here:

http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/04/how-do-i-store-the-counts-of-all-tables.html